# Vue Apollo instance option issues, can't configure properly

Tags: vue.js, apollo-client

I'm working on integrating Vue-Apollo into a Laravel project right now. I was able to get Vue up and running just fine. Now I am trying to integrate Apollo and it isn't working. I feel like I'm missing something really simple but can't locate it.
Here's my `App` component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
    }
</script>
```

my blade template:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <App>
                    <h1>Here</h1>
                    <manufacturers-component></manufacturers-component>
                    <product-groups-component></product-groups-component>
                    <products-component></products-component>
                </App>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Lastly, my JS where I instantiate my Vue:

```
require('./bootstrap');


import Vue from 'vue'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'

import App from './components/App'

Vue.component('manufacturers-component', require('./components/ManufacturersComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('product-groups-component', require('./components/ProductGroupsComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('products-component', require('./components/ProductsComponent.vue'));

 const httpLink = new HttpLink({
     uri: 'http://homestead.test/graphql'
 })

 const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
     link: httpLink,
     cache: new InMemoryCache()
 })

 Vue.use(VueApollo)

 const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
     defaultClient: apolloClient
 })

 const vue_app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    apolloClient,
    render: h => h(App)
 });
```

The thing is it does mount the `App` component briefly, I see a flash of the h1 content reloading the page, but then goes blank. No errors pop up, I've stepped through the loading process and can't find anything sticking out as wrong. No errors are thrown either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML in the blade file is being replaced with the content of the App component once it's mounted, hence the brief appearance and subsequent white page. Move the markup from the blade file into your App component:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h1>Here</h1>
        <manufacturers-component></manufacturers-component>
        <product-groups-component></product-groups-component>
        <products-component></products-component>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
    }
</script>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="app"></div>
@endsection
```